# Filter dataframes in R if y1 and y2 both are >0 but keeping 0 values if only one of them is 0

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I am having trouble filtering my dataframe which is the following:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("q","q","z","z","v","v"),
                  B = c("a","b","a","b","b","a"),
                  C = c( 10, 12, 5, 0, 0, 0))
```

Now I do want to get rid of the 0s since they mean NA, but only if both values for a value in A are so. So I do want to keep both Zs but want to get rid of both Vs. 
This is my desired output:

```
A B C
q a 10
q b 12
z a 5
z b 0
```

However i can only get it to show this(with all 0 values included):

```
A B C
q a 10
q b 12
z a 5
z b 0
v b 0
v a 0
```

Or with Bs 0 value removed aswell. 
I already tried removing values below 0 but this removed the z value aswell, which I need for my analysis.

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: `df[!with(df, ave(C, A, FUN = function(i) all(i==0))),]`, but there is probably a dupe. I am searching for one now

Comment: A solution using dplyr: `library(dplyr) df2 <- df %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(!all(C == 0))`